# I am working on an Angular project. I need to pass an array from one component to another using router.navigate but unable to do it

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on Angular 6. I am trying to pass an array from component AAA to component BBB using router.navigate method.In component BBB I am trying to get the array using snapshot, but unable to get the array.

Component AAA

```
export class AAA implements OnInit {
private testCases: TestCase[] = [];

constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
const value = form.value;
console.log("form values: "+value.testid);
const newTestCase = new TestCase(value.testid, value.testPriority, 
value.testSummary);
console.log(newTestCase);
this.testCases.push(newTestCase);
console.log(this.testCases);
this.navToTable(this.testCases);
}

navToTable(testCase: TestCase[]) {
this.router.navigate(['table', {testCase}]);
}
}
```

component BBB

```
export class BBB {
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
this.testCase = this.route.snapshot.params['testCase'];
console.log(this.testCase);  
}

printing output as [object object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication between two routed components usually mean you pass an ID or a string through the URL.

Passing a whole array is a bad practice, to not say terrible.

Instead, consider taking a look at [Components interactions](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) (hint : you can also use a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) combined to a service, which offers more features when it comes to routing)

Comment: I gave you the documentation, that's the code suggestion ! you still need a shared service though.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to exchange large amount of data between two routes, you should create a  dedicated service for this which acts like a singleton wrapping a stack where you push and pop this data. Of course you could aso do a service containing a map where you fetch the data for a specific component.

Nevertheless, this might still be bad practice as it is uncommon, hard to debug and error-prone.

Resolvers might work as well, but I would use the service solution if it is not possible to pass IDs for any reason.